# How to check whether an integer is divisible by a decimal?

Tags: javascript

If use `%` then it works for integer%interger:

```
10%5 == 0 return true;
10%3 != 0 return false;
```

But how to use code to check whether variable a can

```
a%0.002 == 0 return true;
a%0.002 != 0 return false;
```

a could be integer or float.

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: By 'divisible by a decimal', you mean the quotient is an integer? Or do you mean if it returns a rational number?

Comment: Well, I just notice the question is very dumb, I just want to check a a result of the division(any number divided by decimal) is any integer, like Miky mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to verify the division results in an integer:

```
var n=25, dec=.0125;

(n/dec)%1==0; //   returned value: (Boolean) true


var n=25, dec=.022;

(n/dec)%1==0; //  returned value: (Boolean) false
```

Comment: Yeah this is the most simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First, divisibility is defined only for integers. So your statement is not necessarily mathematically correct.

Now, if you just want to see if a number can be expressed as an integer multiple of another decimal number, than the best way do do that is perhaps to implement a function that checks whether the result of the division is an integer.

In general, you can think of the `%` (modulo operator) as performing an integer division, and returning the remainder.

Comment: "divisibility is defined only for integers", not so in [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.3) `...in ECMAScript, [the % operator] also accepts floating-point operands`. The difficulty is that many decimal values can't be represented exactly, but the OP will discover that next. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need some custom function like

```
function test(a, b){
    var result = a / b;
    return Math.round(result) == result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and can we integrate this function with integer divisible with integer? just like it can check decimal "divisible" to decimal but also integer divisible to integer